# Calling External API with Tibco BW Vers6

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, tibco, tibco-business-works

I'm really new to this community. But anyway I got to call an external api (a paypal api) through Tibco and have absolutely no idea how to do it. I've been on this for days but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank yall so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of service external API is exposing? If it is REST service, you can use REST/JSON palette with Invoke REST API or Send HTTP Request.
If it is SOAP, there is different approach in place.
But what you need to acquire is service specification (ideally sample request and endpoint). Share details and maybe I can help more.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the reply! I've already submitted the assignment and managed to do it already. :)